# How to add new input field in categories "opencart"?

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x

How to add a new input field in opencart admin categories similar to name or description fields? Anyone help?

Comment: In Tanmoy answer, after 3: form template found in admin/view/template/catalog/category_form.tpl 4. Go to /admin/model/catalog/category.php or /system/storage/modification/admin/model/catalog/category.php and update queries in methods addCategory(), editCategory()

Answer (score 1):

1.First you have add oi label name in the language file.
  For this you have to go
       Admin->Language->[your Language folder ]->catalog->category.php.
   like,
    $_['new_field']             = 'New field:';

2. Goto Admin->Controller->catalog->category.php. getForm() function.Fetch that language field like this,

   $this->data['new_field'] = $this->language->get('new_field');

3.Now go to you template page,add your new field
like this,

Add one input box name as field.
By this you can add new field in the category page and for the other pages just changing the language folder and controller function.